# Modify unique_together contraint on through model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, constraints

I have a Rate model defined as follow:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'reviewer': True})
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.IntegerField(
        default=100,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0),
            MaxValueValidator(100)
        ]
    )
    level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    objects = RateManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'api_project_reviewers'
        unique_together = ('user', 'project', 'level')
```

It is an intermediate model between my User and my Project model.

It's created like this on my project model:

```
reviewers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="review_project", through='Rate')
```

I added the unique_together constraint on the model because I want to be able to have 2 entries as:

- Entry 1: User 1, Project 1, rate 100, level 1
- Entry 2:  User 1, Project 1, rate 100, level 2

Basically I want to be able to associate one user to the same project multiple time, changing the level.

But when I do it I receive:

> IntegrityError at /admin/api/user/6/change/ duplicate key value
> violates unique constraint
> "api_project_reviewers_project_id_user_id_cd9f7f42_uniq" DETAIL:  Key
> (project_id, user_id)=(1, 6) already exists.

which is totally right byt shouldn't raise an error.

How can I remove the unique_together constraint on user and project ?

As suggested by sudden_appearance, I tried to do this:

```
reviewers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="review_project", through='Rate')
```

but I still got the same issue
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `symmetrical=False` on m2m model

Try changing

```
reviewers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="review_project", through='Rate')
```

to

```
reviewers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="review_project", through='Rate', symmetrical=False)
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: It allows you making duplicate rows on m2m model, when you use intermidiate model

Comment: you are right, regarding the documentation it seems to be the option I want however, this is not working. DO you think this is because my db is already populated ?

Comment: Also, will this allow me to create more than 2 entries with the same user and project ?